# Convert null to Enum.NULL

Tags: java, enums

I have an Enum like this:

```
public enum Type{
    CSV, EXCEL, PDF, URL, NULL
}
```

now I read a String from an xml-file and use `Type.valueOf(string);` to parse the value to the enum. if this part does not exist in the xml-file, the string is `null` and not `"null"`. Is there a way to convert `null` to `"null"` or should change the `return null;` to `return "null";`? or should null not even be a part of the enum?

Comment: There is a difference between a `null` instance of `String` and a `String` `"null"`. If the XML expect to get a `String` like `"null"`, I would use `"null"` for the `ENUM.NULL`.

Comment: @AxelH so you would change the return value?

Comment: Why would you prefer the string literal `"null"` to `null` when the ideal would be to have a value of the enum? A missing `Type` value can be represented by `null`, rather than `"null"`. Could you perhaps explain the reasoning behind your preference?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele i get a string from the xml which should be case insensitive. because of that i use `.toUpperCase()` which throws an NPE if its null. and i am looking for the best way to work around this issue

Comment: As it would match the XML expectation, yes. But it depends on what you can update. Since you said "_if this part does not exist in the xml-file_", it would be more logic to get a `null`, but I don't know what is in your hand to make it work with `null`

Comment: both answers are great and sadly i can't accept both. i now use a custom method to get the enumeration value like both suggested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you should do is use something else than `NULL` and parse that case differently:

```
public enum Type {
  CSV, EXCEL, PDF, URL, NONE;
  public static Type from(String text) {
    if (text == null) {
      return NONE;
    } else {
      return valueOf(text.toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

Or better yet, use optionals:

```
public enum Type {
  CSV, EXCEL, PDF, URL; // Note the absence of NULL/NONE/WHATEVER
  public static Optional<Type> from(String text) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(text)
      .map(String::toUpperCase)
      .map(Type::valueOf);
  }
}
```

Comment: sadly i can't use optional as i have to work with java 7. yet thanks for your effort and ill surely get to my goal with the answers

Comment: Great idea with `Optional` (sad to hear that OP can't use it). But I also want to give a hint for a one line solution: `return Optional.ofNullable(name).map(String::toUpperCase).map(Type::valueOf).orElse(NULL);`

Comment: Thanks both! :) @StefanWarminski for the future, feel free to edit answers to add such a minor change ;)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer If you can't use `java.util.Optional` because you're still on Java 7, you can always use [Guava's own `Optional`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) ([see explanations here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)), which is the basis of Java 8's own  `Optional`.

Answer (score 4):

If you call `Type.valueOf(null)` you'll get a `NullPointerException`. So I would suggest two solutions:

1. write a utility function which includes a `null`check:

   ```
   public static Type getType(String name) {
       if (name == null)
           return Type.NULL;
       else
           return Type.valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
   }
   ```
2. create a map from the name to the field (except for `NULL`) and add a getter to your enum:

   ```
   public enum Type {
       CSV, EXCEL, PDF, URL, NULL;

       private static final Map<String, Type> TYPE_BY_NAME = new HashMap<>();
       static {
           TYPE_BY_NAME.put(CSV.name(), CSV);
           TYPE_BY_NAME.put(EXCEL.name(), EXCEL);
           TYPE_BY_NAME.put(PDF.name(), PDF);
           TYPE_BY_NAME.put(URL.name(), URL);
           TYPE_BY_NAME.put(null, NULL);
       }

       public static Type getType(String name) {
           String s = name == null ? null : name.toUpperCase();
           return TYPE_BY_NAME.get(s);
       }
   ```

The second solution needs a bit more typing but you don't get an exception if the name does not exist. If you're sure that only the fields of your enum are given I would prefer the first solution.

Comment: i expect to get the values of the enum as case insensitive string or null. yet it can be typed in everything. also in some point of my code i use a map to have a string assigned to every type of the enum